# Can I access the stored favicons for bookmarks using the Firefox extension API?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm writing an extension for Firefox 57+ (using the WebExtensions API). Is it possible to access the locally stored favicon for a given URL/bookmark? I'm thinking something like `file://{%PROFILE%}/favicons/{% URL %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bug 1315616 - Give extensions access to cached favicon URLs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1315616) tracks this feature request.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's currently not possible. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1411120 tracks this feature request.